# Samsung Note 3 Phone - Clicking camera button fails to take picture

Tags: camera, samsung

Frequently, I see x1.0 in the middle of my camera preview screen, to the left of a small white box.  I'd like to know what exactly that means, but it seems like when it is there, I cannot take a picture.  Absolutely nothing happens when I click the camera button.

I have taken lots of photos with the phone, but sometimes I fall into the above scenario, and it seems like the only thing I can do is to back out and restart the default camera app.

Comment: I would guess that's a zoom indicator. Does the Note 3's camera app allow you to pinch to zoom? Maybe the app is getting hung up for some reason and misinterpreting your tap as part of a pinch gesture.

Comment: I just confirmed with the pinch gesture - and can go from x1.0 to x4.0, and at least this morning, every press of the camera button has taken a picture.   Could it have something to do with auto-focus, or the camera still trying to focus?  Yesterday, I was taking a picture of my driver's license, and I've also had it happen at events where there was a lot of movement.

Comment: Could it be because I'm shaking a little bit?  I've seen the box turn green and red too, which apparently means it's in focus.  I was just showing 3 guys at work, and they also seem to be baffled.  It will work fine 90% of the time, but once it goes "bad", I need to figure out what it wants to "be happy" and take the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I knew why you have x1.0 appeared on the screen and can't take photo. I had the same problem and found out the answer. If two fingers touch the mon, it will appear x1.0 in order to zoom, and if there is still one finger on the mon and haven't move away, you can't press the camera button until all the fingers have moved away from the mon, the camera button will function again!